# Error: Cannot find test-cloud.exe, the path specified by "--uitest-tools-dir" was not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest, xamarin-test-cloud

Trying to run UITest using TestCloud in AppCenter for Xamarin Forms project, both Android and iOS, on both I receive same error when trying to run tests via the `appcenter-cli`.

I am using following command:

```
appcenter test run uitest --app "[dir of iOS project]" --devices d675398e --app-path [Dir of IPA file] --test-series "master" --locale "en_US" --build-dir [Dir of UITEst project] --uitest-tools-dir [Dir of tools]
```

Anyone else came across similar issue and manage to solve it?

Comment: are you specifying the path using "--uitest-tools-dir"?  Are you sure the value you're passing is correct?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried not to use specific path, since application suppose to look up for test-cloud.exe on it's own in parent directories. Received same error.

Comment: Please could you add an example cli command to your question? (Stripping out anything sensitive as you see fit). Also make sure you're on the latest version of appcenter-cli and UITest :)

I'd also recommend reaching out to support (you can do so by using the Intercom dialog on the bottom right of the App Center website).

Comment: Hi @OwenNiblock Yes I have done already, They are just taking days to reply and I thought make someone here came across similar problem. In both cases App center and UITest I updated nuget packages, I even used older versions just to see if that would work.

Comment: Did you used relative or absolute path to the uitest-tools-dir? I had a similar issue when I tried to use the relative path.

Comment: @sanjar I have used absolute path, I also tried not to use the path at all, as it is only optional. No success. Thx for all the answers guys, I appreciate the effort and time taken to find solution for this!

Comment: What's in the directory that you're setting as the UITest tools directory?

Comment: it has lib folder, ThirdPArtyNotices.txt, tools folder that contains test-cloud.exe, Xamarin.UITest-License.rtf, Xamarin.UITest.2.2.2.nupkg file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `--uitest-tools-dir [Dir of tools]` parameter is incorrect. This parameter needs to point to the tools folder directly (the folder which contains `test-cloud.exe`).

So you should change this command parameter to be: `--uitest-tools-dir [Dir of tools]/tools`

It may also be useful to check the logic in the code (the `appcenter-cli` is open source) so if you're ever not sure what's going on - just take a look at the code.

[The logic referred to in the error you're seeing is here](https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter-cli/blob/88758d81c33031dc685624d3f04314d3669c13be/src/commands/test/lib/uitest-preparer.ts#L184)

Comment: Users/wojciech/Perforce/Wojciech/LB/src/dev_wb/VMD/packages/Xamarin.UITest.2.2.2/lib/tools This is the path im directing to, so I have been directing to the correct folder.

Comment: Try: ~/Perforce/Wojciech/LB/src/dev_wb/VMD/packages/Xamarin.UITest.2.2.2/tools

Comment: Works! I mean I got a different error but I have moved on from that one. Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately, My --uitest-tools-dir parameter is correct, but this still does not work

Comment: What does your --uitest-tools-dir look like? (both the path and the contents that the path points to).